# JBOSS Eclipse Integration

Tags: eclipse, jboss, integration

I am working with Eclipse and JBOSS. I was wondering if there is a way to do hot in-place deployment for a web project, by  integrating the JBOSS server with Eclipse.
By hot in-place deployment, I mean, I should be able to view the change made to a jsp , by refreshing the page on the browser, not required to go through the routine , build-deploy-test cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). That has everything you need.

Comment: Sorry, but, could you tell me what exactly to look for in there..?

Comment: Look here: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.CR1/en/as/html/modules.html
And use the "incremental publish" feature.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss Tools seems to do auto-redeploy by default when you create a web application with their wizard: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.CR1/en/GettingStartedGuide/html/jsp_application.html#AutoRedeploy

AFAIK every time you save a JSP they copy it to the application deploy directory in JBoss, but if your source layout matches the WAR layout they might run the application directly from your project directory (I know some versions of WTP did this with Tomcat, but with JBoss it's probably harder).

Answer (score 0):

You are after "Exploded Hot Deployment" - deploys a directory of your files rather than an archive and then any subsequent "explode" will only deploy changes rather than the whole project (depending on how you have Ant configured).

Frameworks like Seam do this for you. Maybe worth grabbing a build.xml file from them and modifying it for your use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [JSP-Weaver](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jsp-weaver/)?

Here is the Wikipedia description:

> JSP Weaver is a JavaServer Pages
>   interpreter. Unlike JSP compilers it
>   evaluates the JSP files directly,
>   without generating or compiling
>   intermediate Java source files for the
>   JSP Java servlet.
>
> Although this sacrifices some
>   performance on page rendering (10%-20%
>   overhead depending on the compiler in
>   question) it enables a much faster
>   reloading of changes made to the
>   source of the JSP file (10-20 times
>   decrease in time depending on the page
>   and the compiler in question).
>
> Unlike simpler attempts at
>   interpreting JSP-like syntax (e.g.
>   Facelets) it supports embedded Java
>   statements called Scriptlets (a
>   standard JSP feature). This allows
>   full compatibility with the JSP
>   specification versions 1.0 to 2.1.

I also agree with Sietse in you should check out JBoss Tools.  It is a great free alternative to the JBoss Developer Studio

Comment: JSP Weaver just replaces the JSP engine in the server with an interpreter, it doesn't have anything to do with the deployment.